# C# GeoCoordinate Return Value

Tags: c#, geocoding

I'm using this function below to find the distance between two sets of Latitude and Longitude pairs.  It seems to work fine but I have two questions.  It returns the value in Kilometers rather than miles (I am in the US), and the kilometer value seems to be off by three decimal places?  The values it returns are something like this: 34366.7661043296 which is the distance from Valencia, CA to Burbank, CA about 35 kilometers.  Why in kilometers, and more importantly why the decimal issue?  It would be great if it just returned something like 36.50 miles.  Any help greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
public static double GetDistance(double sLatitude, double sLongitude, double eLatitude, double eLongitude)
{
    var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(sLatitude, sLongitude);
    var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(eLatitude, eLongitude);
    return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);            
}
```

Comment: Why not wrap to divide the output by 1609.344 to get the miles and be done with it? Say `return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord)/1609.344;` as a last line

Comment: To be accurate, if the method returns the value `34366.7661043296` it is returning a value in `metres` not `kilometres`.  And I agree with @EugenRieck's suggestion.

Comment: ok, I guess I see my oversight now, the function is returning the value in meters, not kilometers?  Burbank to Valencia is about 34 kilometers, not 34366 kilometers.  Sorry, I see that now.  Had assumed it was kilometers.  I'll do as you suggest and divide by 1609.344 - thank you.